# How to make -Wl,-y usable for C++ code

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

With C code you can do

```
gcc -Wl,-y,printf main.c
```

and this is extremely easy to remember, in g++ with C++ code you can't just do

```
g++ -Wl,-y,std::cout main.cpp
```

, so there are other options for C++ code ?

Comment: It would help to explain what `-Wl,-y` actually does, because it's likely there's a solution in C++ that doesn't involve linker flags at all.

Comment: Is it "`--trace-symbol=symbol`
Print the name of each linked file in which symbol appears" ?

Comment: @BenVoigt yes, it tells you the library used to resolve the symbol

Comment: Apparently you need to mangle the name; i.e. g++ -Wl,-y,_ZSt4cout main.cpp

Comment: yes, and how I get that name for any given entity in my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nm -opr to examine symbol names and determine the one you want.

(The original version of this answer gave the reverse of the desired answer, by suggesting c++filt).

Comment: can you provide a working example ? because this utility doesn't really looks like a solution in this case